# How to convert animated GIF to AVD

Tags: android, react-native, animated-gif, android-vectordrawable, objectanimator

I have a GIF file which actually shows 5 png images in infinite loop to show animation. I want to create an Android vector graphics of this GIF. So can we use bitmap images in AVD ?
Can some one tell me how to shows images in sequence so that they look as animation?

AVD image i want to in React native Android app, I don't want to use lottie or fresco. My app is running on RN .58 and Android API 22.

Thanks in advance